# ContentEditable Div Error just in Opera

Tags: html, contenteditable

I got a problem with a contenteditable div in Opera. I can edit the div when it contains content, but I  can't do anything when the div is empty?

```
<div contenteditable=true></div>
```

Any workarounds or library for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just fix your markup, `<div/>` is not correct enclosing tag.

```
<div contenteditable=true></div>
```

It looks like Opera doesn't allow you to edit content of elements that were not properly enclosed.

Comment: That's not the problem. I created the div using javascript

Comment: @Woho87 Then please create a demo. I've tried it and everything works fine, I'm able to edit content of empty element even in Opera.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a text node inside with length > 0 to write its not just in opera